# Yarn queue capacity not working as expected for CORE nodes on EMR (emr-5.26.0)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, capacity

Usecase => Create two YARN queues: Q1 and Q2 with the configuration below.

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "capacity-scheduler",
      "Properties": {
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues" : "Q1,Q2",
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.Q1.capacity" : "60",
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.Q2.capacity" : "40",
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.Q1.accessible-node-labels" : "*", 
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.Q2.accessible-node-labels" : "*",
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.Q1.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity" : "60",
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.Q2.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity" : "40",
"yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.Q1.accessible-node-labels.CORE.maximum-capacity" : "60"
      }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-site",
      "Properties": {
        "yarn.acl.enable": "true",
        "yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class": "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler"
      }
  }
]
```

**Expected behavior**: Q1 should not use more than 60% percent of CORE nodes so that 40% is always available for Q2. See [YARN doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Queue_Properties) to understand Queue configs. Another reference to understand max-capacity configuration in [this book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hadoop-the-definitive/9781491901687/ch04.html).

**Actual behavior**: Q1 uses more than 60%, i.e. "Absolute Used Capacity" for the queue "Q1" is greater than the "Absolute Configured Max Capacity".

This is not as per the [YARN documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Queue_Properties).
I would like to understand the cause behind this behavior. And alternatives solutions to this.

**Update 1:**
This problems seems to be only with the CORE nodes. If I specify below, it works as expected for task nodes. 
        yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.Q1.maximum-capacity: 60

EMR creates CORE nodes under the YARN node label as **CORE**. By default, EMR creates this node label. More on [the YARN node labels](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html) and [EMR 5.19.0 using the YARN node label feature](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-master-core-task-nodes.html). IMHO, while using YARN node label feature for CORE nodes, EMR is either over-riding or have broken this configuration for CORE nodes.

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://mitylytics.com/2017/11/configuring-multiple-queues-aws-emr-yarn/)

Comment: @Lamanus I already saw that. If you see the configuration that I have specified and the book example that I have given is on similar lines.

Comment: Updating the question with further analysis